# Is [hypothetical] [experiment] allowed

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Both [hypothetical](/questions/tagged/hypothetical) and [experiment](/questions/tagged/experiment) seem to be perfect [meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for Stack Overflow as they can't work as the only tag on any question. I guess there is no room for *hypothetical* questions anyways. Would like to hear your opinion to decide if I should start the removal process.

Comment: Both should just be burninated. And by the sound of it, there are some VTC targets here too.

Comment: @Chenmunka: These tags are on *Stack Overflow*, not meta.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Stack Overflow tags and the request is already [status-completed]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both tags are ripe for burnination. I've gone through and:

- Removed them from the handful of questions (only 21 and 44 posts for these)
- Voted to close any that are blatantly off-topic or too broad; Stack Overflow is about *practical, answerable problems*, not hypothetical, experimental thought puzzles.

Both [hypothetical](/questions/tagged/hypothetical) and [experimental](/questions/tagged/experimental) are now

[image: tag burninated]

In the process I also came across the [developer-psychology](/questions/tagged/developer-psychology), a real gem of a tag with two remaining questions that need closing and deleting; feel free to help out there!

Questions I VTCed for:

- a custom reason (way outside the stated topics for SO):

  - [given N stacks and no dynamic memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865472/given-n-stacks-and-no-dynamic-memory)
  - [A faster sorting algorithm given a magic data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973316/a-faster-sorting-algorithm-given-a-magic-data-structure)
  - [Would it be possible to have a UTF-8-like encoding limited to 3 bytes per character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011272/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-utf-8-like-encoding-limited-to-3-bytes-per-charac)
  - [Dual neural networks experiment (one logical, one emotional)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284179/dual-neural-networks-experiment-one-logical-one-emotional)
  - [Input lag tester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404231/input-lag-tester)

- too broad:

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130265/lots-of-the-tests-in-the-test-suite-are-failing-any-advice-on-debugging-it
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239952/is-there-any-good-ways-to-do-batch-processing-in-scientific-experiments
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342050/how-to-build-a-python-encryption-algorithm
  - [Validate an html document that I wrote with document.write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559166/validate-an-html-document-that-i-wrote-with-document-write)
  - [How to find and eliminate sources of randomness in a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182580/how-to-find-and-eliminate-sources-of-randomness-in-a-java-program)
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901985/global-read-only-session-persistant-user-editable-textual-browser-data

- primarily opinion based:

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411960/alternative-to-filename-extensions
  - [What would a multithreaded UI api look like, and what advantages would it provide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208038/what-would-a-multithreaded-ui-api-look-like-and-what-advantages-would-it-provid)
  - [Programming experiments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322414/programming-experiments)
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304476/memorable-pedagogic-programming-experiments
  - [Would there be benefits to a struct String in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098692/would-there-be-benefits-to-a-struct-string-in-net)

- seeking external resources / recommendations:

  - [Tools for analysing experimental data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643317/tools-for-analysing-experimental-data)
  - [Existence of a table generation framework for experiments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591864/existence-of-a-table-generation-framework-for-experiments)
  - [Modify TCP/IP protocol on router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583958/modify-tcp-ip-protocol-on-router)
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713976/open-source-free-template-website-software-for-biological-experiments-managin
  - [Inspiring web experiments and technical demos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632036/inspiring-web-experiments-and-technical-demos)
  - [Experimental IDE concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066834/experimental-ide-concepts)
  - [Way to store large amount of experiments and corresponding results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198152/way-to-store-large-amount-of-experiments-and-corresponding-results)
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923895/windows-c-how-to-time-code-for-experiments-or-how-to-have-code-self-profile
  - [Tool for manipulating results of large set of computational experiments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782458/tool-for-manipulating-results-of-large-set-of-computational-experiments)
  - [Free Hadoop Cluster for Experiments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078504/free-hadoop-cluster-for-experiments)
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150078/best-software-for-running-a-psych-lab-experiment

Comment: "hypothetical is now burninated, with experiment to follow" - I hope with some close votes along the way - I'm sure many of those aren't particularly appropriate questions.

Comment: @Dukeling: I'll add a list of questions I voted to close. There were OK questions there that just didn't need that tag. In many ways, `experiment` is actually worse for closable questions.

Comment: Seems most [tag:psychology] questions are also off topic, but possibly not particularly bad.